# How can I set PUT parameters in Zend's HTTP Client

Tags: zend-http-client

I'm trying to use the PUT method with the [Zend Http Client](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.7/Zend_Http/Client/Zend_Http_Client.html) but I'm unable to add parameters to the request.

Here's my code snippet:

```
$client = new Zend_Http_Client($this->url);
$client->setAuth($this->username, $this->password, Zend_Http_Client::AUTH_BASIC);
$client->setParameterPut('fruit',$var);
$result = $client->request('PUT');
$data = $result->getBody();
```

I have already declared "url", "username", "password" and "var" previously in the code.

Comment: Would be nice if you could also include the error you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

While you didn't include the error, there is no such method in Zend_Http_Client as `$client->setParameterPut()`.

PUT requests do not have "parameter" semantics. To send content in a PUT request, you most likely want to use `$client->setRawData($data, $enctype)` where `$data` is your data, that is parameters encoded in some form, and `$enctype` is the Content-type, which is optional but recommended or required by most APIs.

Comment: Isn't setRawData() used for xml/json/zip data? I'm trying to pass a variable whose value is dynamic.

Comment: @user2509780 the data can be anything you want, static or dynamic. If you are passing "parameters", they must be encoded somehow (e.g. url-encoded as used in standard HTML forms), and your server needs to know how to decode them, but as long as that is known the contents can be anything.